# Out of memory error on using onSnapshot Firebase in REACTjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, out-of-memory

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(usersCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      setUsers(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    });
  });
```

I think this is the main cause of this problem because when I was using **getDocs** I was not getting any errors. I found out that using **onSnapshot** instead would help getting real-time updates on the website. But after letting the website run for a while, I get an error

> React is out of memory.

Is there a way to fix this leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running this effect on every render, and never unsubscribing. Use a dependency array to only run the effect when relevant things change, and return an unsubscribe function to clean up when the component unmounts or the dependencies change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(usersCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
    setUsers(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  });
  return unsubscribe; // <--- return teardown function
}, []); // <--- added dependency array
```

If usersCollectionRef can change, then the dependency array might need to be `[usersCollectionRef]`